Lifting projective representations of the dihedral group
Let $ Dih(n) $ be the dihedral group of order $ 2n $. So for example $ Dih(3) $ is the symmetries of an equilateral triangle and is isomorphic to the symmetric group on three letters, $ S_3 $.
A homomorphism $ Dih(n) \to PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ is called a (complex) projective representation of $ Dih(n) $. Let $ \pi: GL(n,\mathbb{C}) \to PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ be the standard projection map. Is it true that every projective representation of $ Dih(n) $ can be obtained by composing $ \pi $ with a linear representation of either $ Dih(2n) $ or $ Dic(n) $, where $ Dic(n) $ is the dicyclic group of order $ 4n $?
Equivalently, does every irreducible projective representation of $ Dih(n) $ lift to a linear representation of either $ Dih(2n) $ or $ Dic(n) $?
For example I know that this is true for $ n=2 $; The Klein 4 group $ Dih(2) $ has exactly two Schur covering groups $ Dih(4) $ and $ Dic(2) $ (sometimes called the quaternion group $ Q_8 $).

I'll point out that $Dic(n)$ and $Dih(n)$ have then same character tables when $n$ is even, and that $Dic(n)/Z(Dic(n))\cong Dic(n)$ for all $n$. Does this help?
Edit: matched your notation
